# React Native voice call for android and iOS 13+

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, voip

My client wants me to develop one to one voice call facility for iOS and Android mobile app. Its a simple voice calling app.
We are using aws for authentication and data storage of the user. So I checked aws services for voice calling facility. I went through aws chime but as I understood it is only for meeting initiation, video calling and screen sharing facility. Not immediate voice calling like whatsapp.

I went through documentations of react-native-callkeep and react-native-voip-call but I did not understood do they need any server for voice calling or it can be done directly without any server support.

Please help me with the correct way to implement voice calling feature. What all libraries and servers do we need for this feature.

Thank you